# Is there a way to make JPQL @Query annotation dynamic?

Tags: java, jpql

Currently, I am trying to make a JPQL query in my repository within my Spring project,

this is my current code for the repository

```
@Query("select d.denda from DataTransaksi d WHERE d.tanggal= 1170130 AND d.nama = Suratno AND d.masaPajak=2016")
    Collection<DataTransaksiModel> findAllDenda();
```

However, `d.tanggal`, `d.nama`, and `d.masaPajak` will not always be the same. I want to use the method here

```
        if(file.getContentType().equalsIgnoreCase("application/vnd.ms-excel")) {
            InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream());
            CSVParser csvParser = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(input);
            for (CSVRecord record : csvParser) {
                String tanggal = record.get("Tanggal");
                String nama = record.get("Nama WP");
                String masaPajak = record.get("Masa Pajak");
                String denda = record.get("Denda");
                String jumlahSetoran = record.get("Jumlah Setoran");
                String pokok = record.get("Pokok");
                String luasTanah = record.get("L.Tanah");
                String luasBangunan = record.get("L. Bangunan");
```

Where `d.tanggal`, `d.nama`, and `d.masaPajak`is based on `tanggal`, `nama`, and `masaPajak`from the CSV that is uploaded.

Is there a way to make the value of `d.tanggal`, `d.nama`, and `d.masaPajak`dynamic and follow the variable that we set?

Answer (score 1):

Just use query placeholders

```
@Query("select d.denda from DataTransaksi d WHERE d.tanggal=:x AND d.nama = :y AND d.masaPajak=:z")
    Collection<DataTransaksiModel> findAllDenda(Longx,String y,Long z);
```

Adjust `x,y,z` types to suit your needs. Also you can renam params to be more descriptive

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this, One way is to use indexed query params. Index value and the method parameter index should match in this case as below.

```
@Query("select d.denda from DataTransaksi d WHERE d.tanggal= ?1 AND d.nama = ?2 AND d.masaPajak=?3")
Collection<DataTransaksiModel> findAllDenda( Long x, String y, Long z); // These should be in exact order.
```

Other way is to use the named query parameters, In this way, you are free to define the mapping between the method parameter and the query parameter as below

```
@Query("select d.denda from DataTransaksi d WHERE d.tanggal= :x AND d.nama = :y AND d.masaPajak=:z")
Collection<DataTransaksiModel> findAllDenda( @Param("x") Long x, @Param("y") String y, @Param("z") Long z);
```